# NVM for Windows successfully installed but CMD prompt informs my version of Node.exe not compatible with my Windows version

Tags: node.js, nvm-windows

I'm on a Microsoft Surface Pro X (it features Windows 10 Home on ARM 64-bit processor) trying to install Node.js. I've decided to use NVM for Windows. I can successfully install and get NVM for Windows running correctly. To my understanding, I'm able to install different versions of Node (i.e. 16.16.0 and 16.13.1, for example, both LTS) as shown in below graphic. But when I try to run Node, I get the error "This version of C:\Program Files\Nodejs\node.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher."

[image]

I am not clear on the *why* this is happening. Am I not downloading a version of Node that is compatible on my ARM 64-bit processor? I've read through several closed issues on the GitHub [page](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues) but I haven't encountered someone bringing up this same error. I'm pretty confident it does NOT have to do with the integrity of my symlinks too, or my system environment variables. See below:

[image]

Your help and insight is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: nodejs doesn't have binaries for Win-ARM, you can see all avail bins [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.16.0/), I recommend using docker or WSL as of now.